# In C#, how do you mix a default get with an explicit set?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, setter, automatic-properties

I want to do something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    bool Property
    {
        get;
        set
        {
            notifySomethingOfTheChange();
            // What should I put here to set the value?
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can put there to set the value? Or will I have to explicitly define the `get` and add another field to the class?

Comment: This would be ambiguous to the compiler. Would the set happen before or after `notifySomethingOfTheChange()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You either have a default property, with compiler-generated backing field and getter and/or setter body, or a custom property.

Once you define your own setter, there is no compiler-generated backing field.  You have to make one yourself, and define the getter body also.

Answer (score 14):

There is no way.

- You can either have both setter and getter auto-implemented

  ```
  bool Property { get; set; }
  ```
- Or implement both manually

  ```
  bool Property
  {
      get { return _prop; }
      set { _prop = value; }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

No this is the case where auto-properties are not the best fit, and therefore the point at which you go to proper implemented properties:

```
class Foo
{
    private bool property;
    public bool Property
    {
        get
        {
            return this.property;
        }
        set
        {
            notifySomethingOfTheChange();
            this.property = value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cloud it's quite "planely" obvious you're right ;) The accepted answer is basically the same answer, just without code.

Comment: I feel like that is going to go wright over everyone's heads.

Answer (score -3):

In many cases you can use the "Auto Property" feature 
e.g. public int Age { get; set;  } = 43;

This is a good reference http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2416187

Naji K.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  OP is in a situation where they cannot use an auto property, and has already stated so.